# Behat/Mink doesn't find field by id

Tags: php, behat

I am trying to fill out a field.
Why does Behat not find the field by id?

Input Field:

```
   <input class="js-text-full text-full form-text required" data-drupal-selector="edit-field-article-nr-supplier-0-value" type="text" id="edit-field-article-nr-supplier-0-value" name="field_article_nr_supplier[0][value]" value="" size="60" maxlength="255" placeholder="" required="required" aria-required="true">
```

PHP Code:

```
public function fillField($field, $value)
{
    $field = $this->fixStepArgument($field);
    $value = $this->fixStepArgument($value);
    $this->getSession()->getPage()->fillField($field, $value);
}
```

Behat:

```
When I fill in "edit-field-article-nr-supplier-0-value" with "12"
```

It says it doesn't find a field by id:

```
 When I fill in "edit-field-article-nr-supplier-0-value" with "12"   # Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MinkContext::fillField()
  Form field with id|name|label|value|placeholder "edit-field-article-nr-supplier-0-value" not found. (Behat\Mink\Exception\ElementNotFoundException)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around. I filled out the input filed with javascript

```
  /**
   * @When I fill in :value on the field :field with javascript
   */
  public function findAllInputFields($value, $field){
      $javascript = "window.onload = function () {var e = document.getElementById('$field').value='$value';}";
      $this->getSession()->executeScript($javascript);
  }
```

Important, don't forget the @javascript annotation.

```
@javascript
Scenario: Fill out field
    When I fill in 12 on the field "edit-field-article-nr-supplier-0-value" with javascript
```

If someone has a better solution, please share I would like to know.

Answer (score 1):

Mink's method `fillField()` uses `findField()` to find the field - and `findField()` uses `name` as selector and not `id`. That's why your initial approach didn't work. See [source](https://github.com/minkphp/Mink/blob/master/src/Element/TraversableElement.php) of Mink's class TraversableElement for details.