# Behat/Mink switchToIframe error Exception: invalid argument: 'id' can not be string

Tags: selenium, drupal, behat, mink

I'm using Behat/Mink/Selenium with ChromeDriver in a Drupal site to set input data into a Braintree hosted fields iFrame, But I'm getting the error: Exception: invalid argument: 'id' can not be string. There's a similar issue here on Github, but no answers: 
https://github.com/minkphp/MinkSelenium2Driver/issues/315

FeatureContext.php:

```
<?php

use Behat\Behat\Tester\Exception\PendingException;
use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use Drupal\DrupalExtension\Context\MinkContext;


/**
 * Defines application features from the specific context.
 */
class FeatureContext extends MinkContext {
  /**
   * Initializes context.
   *
   * Every scenario gets its own context instance.
   * You can also pass arbitrary arguments to the
   * context constructor through behat.yml.
   */
  public function __construct() {
  }

  /**
   * @When I fill in cardnumber :arg1 with :arg2
   */
  public function iFillInCardnumberWith($arg1, $arg2) {
    $this->getSession()
      ->getDriver()
      ->switchToIFrame('braintree-hosted-field-number');

    $page = $this->getSession()->getPage();

    $InputField = $page->findField($arg1); 
    $InputField->setValue($arg2);

    $this->getSession()->getDriver()->switchToIFrame(NULL);
  }

}
```

In my feature:

And I fill in cardnumber "Credit Card Number" with "4111111111111111"

Full errors:

```
 Exception: invalid argument: 'id' can not be string
        (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.61)
      Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'

      Driver info: driver.version: unknown in vendor/instaclick/php-webdriver/lib/WebDriver/Exception.php:144
      Stack trace:
      #0 vendor/instaclick/php-webdriver/lib/WebDriver/AbstractWebDriver.php(157): WebDriver\Exception::factory(61, 'invalid argumen...')
      #1 vendor/instaclick/php-webdriver/lib/WebDriver/Session.php(290): WebDriver\AbstractWebDriver->curl('POST', '/frame', Array)
      #2 vendor/behat/mink-selenium2-driver/src/Selenium2Driver.php(428): WebDriver\Session->frame(Array)
      #3 features/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php(51): Behat\Mink\Driver\Selenium2Driver->switchToIFrame('braintree-hoste...')
      #4 [internal function]: FeatureContext->iFillInCardnumberWith('Credit Card Num...', '411111111111111...')
      #5 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Call/Handler/RuntimeCallHandler.php(109): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
      #6 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Call/Handler/RuntimeCallHandler.php(64): Behat\Testwork\Call\Handler\RuntimeCallHandler->executeCall(Object(Behat\Behat\Definition\Call\DefinitionCall))
      #7 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Call/CallCenter.php(140): Behat\Testwork\Call\Handler\RuntimeCallHandler->handleCall(Object(Behat\Behat\Definition\Call\DefinitionCall))
      #8 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Call/CallCenter.php(96): Behat\Testwork\Call\CallCenter->handleCall(Object(Behat\Behat\Definition\Call\DefinitionCall))
      #9 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Tester/Runtime/RuntimeStepTester.php(125): Behat\Testwork\Call\CallCenter->makeCall(Object(Behat\Behat\Definition\Call\DefinitionCall))
      #10 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Tester/Runtime/RuntimeStepTester.php(73): Behat\Behat\Tester\Runtime\RuntimeStepTester->testDefinition(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\InitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\FeatureNode), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\StepNode), Object(Behat\Behat\Definition\SearchResult), false)
      #11 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Hook/Tester/HookableStepTester.php(74): Behat\Behat\Tester\Runtime\RuntimeStepTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\InitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\FeatureNode), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\StepNode), false)
      #12 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/EventDispatcher/Tester/EventDispatchingStepTester.php(84): Behat\Behat\Hook\Tester\HookableStepTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\InitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\FeatureNode), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\StepNode), false)
      #13 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Tester/StepContainerTester.php(59): Behat\Behat\EventDispatcher\Tester\EventDispatchingStepTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\InitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\FeatureNode), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\StepNode), false)
      #14 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Tester/Runtime/RuntimeScenarioTester.php(76): Behat\Behat\Tester\StepContainerTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\InitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\FeatureNode), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\ScenarioNode), false)
      #15 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Hook/Tester/HookableScenarioTester.php(74): Behat\Behat\Tester\Runtime\RuntimeScenarioTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\InitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\FeatureNode), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\ScenarioNode), false)
      #16 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/EventDispatcher/Tester/EventDispatchingScenarioTester.php(114): Behat\Behat\Hook\Tester\HookableScenarioTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\InitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\FeatureNode), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\ScenarioNode), false)
      #17 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Tester/Runtime/IsolatingScenarioTester.php(69): Behat\Behat\EventDispatcher\Tester\EventDispatchingScenarioTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\InitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\FeatureNode), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\ScenarioNode), false)
      #18 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Tester/Runtime/RuntimeFeatureTester.php(84): Behat\Behat\Tester\Runtime\IsolatingScenarioTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\UninitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\FeatureNode), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\ScenarioNode), false)
      #19 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/Hook/Tester/HookableFeatureTester.php(72): Behat\Behat\Tester\Runtime\RuntimeFeatureTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\UninitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\FeatureNode), false)
      #20 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Behat/EventDispatcher/Tester/EventDispatchingFeatureTester.php(82): Behat\Behat\Hook\Tester\HookableFeatureTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\UninitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\FeatureNode), false)
      #21 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Tester/Runtime/RuntimeSuiteTester.php(63): Behat\Behat\EventDispatcher\Tester\EventDispatchingFeatureTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\UninitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Gherkin\Node\FeatureNode), false)
      #22 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Hook/Tester/HookableSuiteTester.php(73): Behat\Testwork\Tester\Runtime\RuntimeSuiteTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\UninitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Testwork\Specification\GroupedSpecificationIterator), false)
      #23 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/EventDispatcher/Tester/EventDispatchingSuiteTester.php(83): Behat\Testwork\Hook\Tester\HookableSuiteTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\UninitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Testwork\Specification\GroupedSpecificationIterator), false)
      #24 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Tester/Runtime/RuntimeExercise.php(71): Behat\Testwork\EventDispatcher\Tester\EventDispatchingSuiteTester->test(Object(Behat\Behat\Context\Environment\UninitializedContextEnvironment), Object(Behat\Testwork\Specification\GroupedSpecificationIterator), false)
      #25 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/EventDispatcher/Tester/EventDispatchingExercise.php(81): Behat\Testwork\Tester\Runtime\RuntimeExercise->test(Array, false)
      #26 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Ordering/OrderedExercise.php(80): Behat\Testwork\EventDispatcher\Tester\EventDispatchingExercise->test(Array, false)
      #27 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Tester/Cli/ExerciseController.php(149): Behat\Testwork\Ordering\OrderedExercise->test(Array, false)
      #28 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Tester/Cli/ExerciseController.php(108): Behat\Testwork\Tester\Cli\ExerciseController->testSpecifications(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Array)
      #29 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Cli/Command.php(63): Behat\Testwork\Tester\Cli\ExerciseController->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      #30 vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Behat\Testwork\Cli\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      #31 vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(987): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      #32 vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(255): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Behat\Testwork\Cli\Command), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      #33 vendor/behat/behat/src/Behat/Testwork/Cli/Application.php(124): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      #34 vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(148): Behat\Testwork\Cli\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
      #35 vendor/behat/behat/bin/behat(34): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
      #36 {main}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with this Docker image selenium/standalone-chrome-debug i.e. no version number so I assume 'latest'.  When I use selenium/standalone-chrome-debug:3.141.59-neon everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the fault lays in your input value for `$arg1`. Given:

```
$page->findField($arg1)->setValue($arg2);
```

Can you change the input to:

```
And I fill in cardnumber "cardnumber" with "4111111111111111"
```

Where `"cardnumber"` is the name attribute of your card number input element. See also [Behat/Mink doesn't find field by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54437349/behat-mink-doesnt-find-field-by-id).

It may also be better to discard the input of that value and just hardcode that name attribute (unless it changes which I doubt it does?):

```
$this->getSession()->getPage()->findField('cardnumber')->setValue($card);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but even removing this part completely I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Works with numerical ID being the index of the iframe on the page:

```
 /**
   * Assert that content is present in an iframe.
   *
   * @Then I see content in iframe with id :id
   */
  public function iSeeContentInIframe($id) {
    $driver = $this->getSession()->getDriver();
    if (!$driver instanceof Selenium2Driver) {
      throw new RuntimeException('Unsupported driver for this step');
    }

    $index = NULL;

    $iframe_elements = $driver->find('//iframe');
    if (!empty($iframe_elements)) {
      foreach ($iframe_elements as $k => $all_page_iframe_element) {
        if ($all_page_iframe_element->getAttribute('id') == $id) {
          $index = $k;
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    if (is_null($index)) {
      throw new ElementNotFoundException($driver, 'iFrame', $id);
    }

    $driver->switchToIFrame($index);

    if (!$driver->find('//body')) {
      throw new Exception(sprintf('The contents of the iFrame with id "%s" was not loaded', $id));
    }

    // Reset frame to the default window.
    $driver->switchToIFrame();
  }
```